# react native run hello world

Tags: android, node.js, windows, react-native

I am using this tutorial 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content
I am using windows 8.
I have print  `npm install -g react-native-cli`. Then

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
```

Then I have read that on windows  I can't use this command  `react-native run-android` so I print `node node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js`
 as suggested here  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html#content
And I get the following output:

> Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react
>   -native\packager\packager.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
>       at startup (node.js:136:18)
>       at node.js:972:3

Myawesomeproject folder has 2 files 
npm-debug.log and package.json

So I feel like something went wrong. Ho can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like react-native init doesn't really work on Windows. [There might be a possible workaround here](https://gist.github.com/davidgilbertson/9bee68548037fe00f2a8)

Comment: @Blake Hair so does it properly works on linux or ubuntu?

Comment: I imagine it might, but I haven't tested it. It looks like a lot of the scripts rely on things fairly common in unix, which is why they don't handle Windows.

Comment: Have you tried the [command](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html#content) `react-native start`, instead calling the packager directly?

Comment: From your error message, it looks as if you don't have a react-native directory in your node modules. Have you made sure that you ran `npm install` before attempting the `node` command?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like npm is not installed correctly on your machine. You may test it by calling `npm install` in the generated directory. If it runs successfully and the `node_modules` folder in that directory is filled your are good to go. You should then run the `react-native init` command again so it can generate everything correctly.